# Get the local notification when the app is in background state?

Tags: ios, nsdate, background-process, uilocalnotification

I want to develop a reminder app. It should remind the people weekly, monthly, quarterly, six months and yearly.

I am using the NSDate property to get the current date and then I am adding the 7 days to the current date, the date after adding the 7 days will be stored in the plist.

I choose the phone/mail/message buttons to remind people. In the button action I compare the current date with date which was saved in plist and then I set the local notification. But the local notifications are not working according to the fire date. When the app is in the foreground it's working fine, but it enters into the background it's not working.

Comment: Do you have notifications enabled for the app in the notification center?

Answer (score 0):

You have to schedule your alarms. Here is a snippet from Apple's documentation:

```
- (void)scheduleAlarmForDate:(NSDate*)theDate
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray*    oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Create a new notification.
    UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarm)
    {
        alarm.fireDate = theDate;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

You can find a lot of helpful information in Apple's documentation ["App States and Multitasking"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), specifically in the section ["Background Execution and Multitasking"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) (it covers exactly your use case).

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, I'd appreciate if you could flag the answer.